# Collapse / Expand collapsibles dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I create a little list of jQuery Monile collapsibles. This is the structure:

```
<div data-role="collapsibleset" data-theme="a" data-content-theme="a">

   <div data-role="collapsible"> 
      Text content
   </div 

  <div data-role="collapsible">
     Text content
   </div >

</div >
```

How can I open all collapsible elements at once when click a button?

Comment: JQM version you're using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The collapsibleset widget only allows one open collapsible at a time by design.  If you want the look of the collapsible set without the behavior, remove the `data-role="collapsibleset"` and instead add `class="ui-collapsible-set"`:

```
<div id="theSet" class="ui-collapsible-set" >
   <div data-role="collapsible" > 
       <h3>Title 1</h3>
      Text content 1
   </div> 
   <div data-role="collapsible" >
      <h3>Title 2</h3>
     Text content 2
   </div>
   <div data-role="collapsible" >
      <h3>Title 3</h3>
     Text content 3
   </div >        
</div >
```

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/MP6DY/)**

**UPDATE:** to expand all from a button click. Given Expand All and Collapse All buttons as follows:

```
<div class="ui-grid-a">
  <div class="ui-block-a"><a id="btnExpand" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all collapseExpand">Expand All</a>
  </div>
  <div class="ui-block-b"><a id="btnCollapse" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all collapseExpand">Collapse All</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Create a handler for the buttons and user `.collapsible("option", "collapsed", true or false);` with a selector that returns all collapsibles in the set:

```
$(document).on("click", ".collapseExpand", function(){
    var collapseAll = this.id == "btnCollapse";
    $('#theSet [data-role="collapsible"]').collapsible("option", "collapsed", collapseAll);
});
```

> Updated **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/MP6DY/2/)**

You might find this article interesting: **http://jqmtricks.wordpress.com/2014/04/25/filterable-opens-matching-collapsibles/** as it includes the expand all and collapse all as well as using the filterable widget to open matching collapsibles as you type in a search box.

Comment: `.collapsible("collapse / expand")` is shorter ;)

Comment: @Omar, for you my friend ;)  - http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/MP6DY/3/. $('#theSet [data-role="collapsible"]').collapsible(this.id == "btnCollapse" ? "collapse" : "expand");